# Android NavigationView onDestroy not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I have a layout with navigation view. The view hierarchy is explained below,

> Navigation View> A > A1
>   Navigation View> B

Now while I am in Fragment A1 if I open Fragment B or Fragment A by clicking the menu in navigation view the onStop or onDestroyView is not invoked in Fragment A1.

I have registered green-bot event in Fragment A1, now as the onStop is not called, the event is never un-registered. So  when I come back to A1 again it's registering a new event and I am getting all events twice.

how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the Activity State Machine: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

How about `onAttach` and `onDetach` methods of `Fragment`. These methods invoked  when fragment is added, removed or replaced in host activity.

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
       //register green-bot event here
    }

@Override
    public void onDetach() {
       //un-register green-bot here
       super.onDetach();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

onStop() is not guaranteed to be called always. unregister your events on onPause() method.

Answer (score 0):

you may forget to call **EventBus.unregister** in onDestory or OnDetech()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onAttach` and `onDetach` as `onDestroy` is called (executed) when activity is destroyed. So when activity is destroyed code under `onDestroy` of `activity` and `fragment` are executed.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
   //register green-bot event here
}

@Override
    public void onDetach() {
       //un-register green-bot here
       super.onDetach();
    }
```